# Source sans pro font in html

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use googles "source sans pro" font in the font-family attribute in CSS, in my HTML site. I use Bootstrap as a front end framework.

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro

How can I achieve that?
Do I have to include the file into my html site?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 33):

Add this string in `head` section of your site:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then use this font:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The instructions are given on the link at the top of the page you show. https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro

You include this in the head of your page:

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and specify the font family in your CSS.

```css
element {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[The fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse)

You can select the fonts you want and you get a link:
for HTML

**https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200,900italic,900,700italic,700,600italic,600,400italic,300italic,300,200italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>**

paste this link in your

Then use this in your css

```
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

so something like this

```
.class{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```