# Add font style with css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have these fonts style added to my my page

```
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

How can I add them to my page with css so that I do not have these external links in my css

I tried this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic');
}
```

but in my console (I use Mlozilla) I got

**downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer**

In Chrome the error says:

**Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic**

Then I downloaded the file associated with the Roboto font and tried

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../../content/fonts/roboto/ek4gzZ-GeXAPcSbHtCeQI_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203696/source-sans-pro-font-in-html/35204067#35204067

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to each google font link and save it to a css file with any name like:

Go to this link then copy and save to a text file named roboto and change the .txt to .css (roboto.css)

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic

Then add this css file to your html like:

```
<link href='roboto.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and do similarly for every google font link.

**For linking woff2 file locally** for example visit this link, font will get downloaded, save it in a fonts named folder with name `opensans-light.woff2`

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTRampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2

then use it like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(fonts/opensans-light.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: IIRC, Google uses user agent sniffing to serve different CSS files depending on the browser.

Comment: @J F , what do you mean, I didn,t get this one .... How does this affect the way I include fonts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @import rule for CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic');
```

Import like this in the head of you CSS file and everything will work

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

- open the link in the `href` method inside your `<link>` tags

  eg
  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,700italic,400italic&subset=latin,cyrillic
- the copy the css style you like
- Paste it in your `.css` file